# Pass two user-defined key-value pairs as parameters when creating Session object. I want to receive it in checkout.session.completed event

Tags: php, stripe-payments

**i have two user-defined key-value pairs**

・'fw_login_flg' => 'TRUE',

・'fw_hoge_id' => 765,

▼index.php

```
$checkoutSession = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'line_items' => [[
    'name' => "demo",
    'amount' => 500,
  ]],
  'payment_intent_data' => [
    'application_fee_amount' => 200,
    'metadata' =>  ['fw_login_flg' => 'TRUE','fw_hoge_id' => 765,],
  ],
  'success_url' => 'https://xxxx/thanks.php',
  'cancel_url' => 'https://xxxx/cancel.php',
  'client_reference_id' => '123',
], [
  'stripe_account' => 'xxxx',
]);
```

▼webhook.php

```
   if ($event->type == 'checkout.session.completed') {
        $session = $event->data->object;
```

Why is 'payment_intent_data' not included in the response?

Comment: Shouldn't `metadata` be outside `payment_intent_data`?

Comment: Which parameter should user-defined key-value pairs go into?

Comment: Try `'payment_intent_data' => [...], 'metadata' => [...]`.

Comment: I encounter the same issue. Have you solved it eventually?